# Removing an element of an array, is removing all javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

trying to remove an element from an array on button click
what's happening is that it seems to be removing all elements on second click?

I've edited this; what I need is for winArray to be reset winArray=[];
evrytime the button is clicked, populate it with mainSlotArr, then remove 1 element, check the console, it does it once only

This is what I've tried so far;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <script>

    mainSlotArr =["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
var winArray =[];
var winSpin = function () {

    winArray =  mainSlotArr.splice(0);


  var winIcon = winArray[0];

winArray = removeFromArray(winArray, winIcon);



}



function removeFromArray(array, el) {
   var pos = array.indexOf(el);
   pos > -1 && array.splice(pos, 1);
    console.log(winArray)

}


    </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="winSpin();">Click Me!</button>              

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does your click function look like?

Comment: Using `Array.prototype.filter` whould be a good practice: `console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter(i => i !== 5));`

Comment: show `mainSlotArr` array items

Comment: assign  winArray to  mainSlotArr after splice statement execute. 

`var winSpin = function () {

   var winArray =[];
    winArray = mainSlotArr.splice(0);

   var winIcon = winArray[0];
    toDel = winArray.indexOf(winIcon);

    winArray.splice(toDel, 1);
    console.log(winArray.length);//this gives me 9 on first click then 0 on second??
 mainSlotArr = winArray;
}`

Comment: @Sachin K that works but I'm not trying to modify the mainSlotArr, I'm trying to copy mainSlotArr to winArray every onClick then delete an element, when button click again do the same, so winArray will equal 10 then 9 everytime

Comment: Actually when you execute "winArray = mainSlotArr.splice (0);" statement, it will remove all element from mainSlotArr. And because of that when you click on second time  it will show 0 to you.

Comment: For that copy this global veriable into any another local veriable and operate on that veriable

Comment: Tried that still not working all arrays get emptied 

` var temp1 = mainSlotArr.splice(0);
    winArray =  temp1.splice(0)`

Comment: Don't understand why this question's been marked -1! everything I've tried hasn't worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  Had time to go back and look at this, the reason that the mainSlotArr and all arrays were being emptied is that I should have been using slice and not splice
(That's what happens when you're working under pressure!!)
Script below works as intended, really can't believe this was marked down though

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

<script>

var mainSlotArr =["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
var mCopy =  mainSlotArr.slice();
var firstTime = true;
var winArray = [];


var winSpin = function () {

 winArray =  mCopy.slice();

console.log(winArray)

var winIcon = winArray[0];

winArray = removeFromArray(winArray, winIcon);



}



function removeFromArray(arr, el) {
   var pos = arr.indexOf(el);
   pos > -1 && arr.splice(pos, 1);
   mCopy =  winArray.slice();

}


    </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="winSpin();">Click Me!</button>              

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `splice` array method not only returns an array of elements in some range, but also removes them from the original array, so when you call `splice` on `mainSlotArr` with an argument of 0, you're telling it "Get ALL elements starting from the first". If you want to get one element at a time then you need to pass `splice` a second argument, that determines the amount of elements to extract `splice(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to remove the first element of the array ?

If so why no use [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

i.e.:

```
var someArr = [1,2,3,4];
someArr.shift(); // returns 1
// now someArr is : [2,3,4]
```

Otherwise just do:

```
function removeFromArray(array, el) {
   var pos = array.indexOf(el);
   pos > -1 && array.splice(pos, 1);
}
removeFromArray(modifiedArray, 'someArrayElement');
```

JSbin [here](https://jsbin.com/numuna/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: At the moment yes I am but moving forward, it could be any element

Comment: Ok, i've update with a simple function that will remove an element form the array. Note that it does not modify the orignal array by reference so you will need to reassign the result of the function to the array.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, I have edited my above post with your code but still no joy

Comment: My bad, I was using the wrong method. I've updated the snippet. Have a look at the jsbin

Comment: Hi still doesn't work when I try to implement it with above code, your code initiates mainSlotArr every time it runs, I need to copy mainSlotArr to winArray, becuase I will need to use it for other functions at the same time, it works once then sets the winArray to 0,